# Reference a class' static field of the same internal module but in a different file?

Tags: module, static, typescript, internal

I'm using TypeScript and require.js to resolve dependencies in my files. I'm in a situation where I want to reference a static field of a class in an other file, but in the same internal module (same folder) and I am not able to access it, even if the Visual Studio pre-compiler does not show any error in my code.
I have the following situation :

**Game.ts**

```
class Game {
    // ...
    static width: number = 1920;
    // ...
}
export = Game;
```

**Launcher.ts**

```
/// <reference path='lib/require.d.ts'/>
import Game = require("Game");

var width: number = Game.width;
console.log(width); // Hoping to see "1920"
```

And the TypeScript compiler is ok with all of this. However, I keep getting "undefined" at execution when running the compiled Launcher.ts.
It's the only reference problem I'm having in my project, so I guess the rest is configured correctly.

I hope I provided all necessary information, if you need more, please ask

Any help is appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems sound, so check the following...

You are referencing `require.js` in a script tag on your page, pointing at `Launcher` (assuming `Launcher.ts` is in the root directory - adjust as needed:

```
<script src="Scripts/require.js" data-main="Launcher"></script>
```

Remove the `reference` comment from `Launcher.ts`:

```
import Game = require("Game");

var width: number = Game.width;
console.log(width); // Hoping to see "1920"
```

Check that you are compiling using `--module amd` to ensure it generates the correct module-loading code (your JavaScript output will look like this...)

```
define(["require", "exports", "Game"], function (require, exports, Game) {
    var width = Game.width;
    console.log(width); // Hoping to see "1920" 
});
```

If you are using Visual Studio, you can set this in `Project > Properties > TypeScript Build > Module Kind (AMD)`

Comment: Yeah, I am referencing `require.js` the way you describe.
I removed the `reference` from `Launcher.ts`, nothing did change; It seems it was in fact unnecessary.

I checked and can confirm I'm using the AMD modules in Visual Studio.
Still, the compiled version of Launcher.ts shows no trace of the static variable :
`define(["require", "exports", "Game"], function(require, exports, Game) {
    console.log(Game);
});`

Comment: `console.log(Game.width)` rather than `console.log(Game)` right?

Comment: I did make a mistake and was trying to log `Game` instead of `Game.width`.
Log `Game` shows an empty Object, but now log `Game.width` actually works and shows me 1920. I'm trying to figure out what caused this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using require.js to load the (external) modules, the Game class must be exported:

```
export class Game {}
```

If you import Game in Launcher.ts like

```
import MyGame = require('Game')
```

the class can be referenced with `MyGame.Game` and the static variable with `MyGame.Game.width`

You should compile the ts files with tsc using option `--module amd` or the equivalent option in Visual Studio

Comment: Thanks, but this made me realize I didn't write that I already exported the class. I just edited my post with that line : `export = Game;`

Comment: And you are sure that you referencing `width` using `Game.Game.width`?

Comment: Trying to reference Game.Game makes the pre-compiler report an error : Game property doesn't exist on a value of type Game.

Comment: if you insert console.log(Game) after the import statement in Launcher.ts, what is the result?

Comment: Here's what I got :
`function Game() {}`

Comment: I am sorry, but I am unable to reproduce your problem. Forget the remark about Game.Game, because by using `export=Game` you can use `Game.width`. My console.log shows `{ [Function: Game] width: 120 }` The only difference is that I am using -m commonjs, but I don't think that is causing the problem.